# can't install Ubuntu 14.04 - black screen - Samsung RV-411

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, system-installation

Newbie here. Got my hands on an old Samsung RV-411 laptop (was running on Win7 Home Premium) and thought of trying out Linux. Followed this website (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/migrating-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu/)  to create bootable USB:
- downloaded Ubuntu 16 LTS 64-bit
- upon reboot, "Error: no suitable video mode found. Booting in blind mode"
- a screen with option to check disk --> no error found
- successfully tried on Ubuntu. So i went ahead with installation (removed Win7, removed previous partition HDD). Wifi was enabled during install
- Completed installation, and removed USB stick and clicked restart
- a black screen with magenta cursor first, but then turned white. And it stayed this way

So I thought that Ubuntu 16 is not compatible with my machine. So I repeated the above steps with ver 14.04. It asked if I wanted to run parallel with ver 16...which means it was successfully installed.

The following is my laptop spec:
- video output nvidia GeForce 315M
- CPU Core i3 2.4Ghz 3MB
- 2GB DDR3 SDRAM

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install and do not pick the install proprietary drivers...like disconnect your internet while installing.  It does not take long.  Try again.  There is nothing to salvage and you wiped win7 anyway and have nothing.    The instructions are quite complex.  Just start where it says universal usb installer and install.

Another option if this does not work. 
Install 14.04 and then do and distribution upgrade.
It should prompt you for that when you click on updates.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Solved it when I manually partitioned the HDD, as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370